# Display script result first on browser then run include file in php

Tags: php, include

I have a script that shows a result done then i call an include file to run at intervals. I would like the script result to display on browser then include file will run in the back. Right now my browser is connecting but showing nothing.I would like the browser echo Done and Logging.

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush(true);
require_once('syslog.php');
$syslog = new Syslog();
$line="My msg";
$hostname = gethostname();
$ip= @$REMOTE_ADDR;
$hostnameip = GetHostByName($ip);
$syslog->Send('127.0.9.1', $hostname." ".$hostnameip." ".$line);
echo"Done";
echo "Logging......";
ob_end_flush();  
include('execute.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll be able to get what you want by calling the `flush()` method right after your `echo` commands.

The [`flush()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) is described as -

> Flushes the write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats.

There are some special considerations when using this function. Certain apache modules and client side buffering will still be enforced, but for now however, I do believe this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have added the flush function but to no success.Still gives me Connecting.... and no echos on my browser

Comment: @mer - you could also try using [`ob_implicit_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php). That's like a global `flush()` command... It should flush after every echo without needing to actually call the `flush()` function.

Comment: I tried the ob_implicit_flush thanks it works I have edited my script on top check out.Thanks Lix (",)

Answer (score 0):

Try [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) before include after last echo.